Linebreaks \n does not work for Richtext or TextSpan in Flutter
This is my CustomMarkupText widget I want to use to display strings that come from the backend correctly (bold or red color). This works but the normal \n doesn't work and is just shown like a normal text in the app:

class CustomMarkupText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  CustomMarkupText(this.text);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final spans = _parseMarkup(text);
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
        children: spans,
      ),
    );
  }

  List<TextSpan> _parseMarkup(String text) {
    final spans = <TextSpan>[];
    final regex = RegExp(r'%r(.*?)%r|%d(.*?)%d|([^%]+)');
    final matches = regex.allMatches(text);

    for (var match in matches) {
      if (match.group(1) != null) {
        // %Rroter Text%R
        spans.add(TextSpan(
          text: match.group(1),
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
        ));
      } else if (match.group(2) != null) {
        // %Bfetter Text%B
        spans.add(TextSpan(
          text: match.group(2),
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ));
      } else if (match.group(3) != null) {
        // Normaler Text (ohne Markup)
        spans.add(TextSpan(text: match.group(3)));
      }
    }

    return spans;
  }
}

This is the original String:
Von morgens bis mittags begrüßt man sich mit %d¡Buenos dias!%d \n Danach bis zum Einbruch der Dunkelheit mit %d¡Buenas tardes!%d \nAb dann begrüßt und verabschiedet man sich mit ¡Buenas noches!. \nIn informellen Situationen kann man auch einfach %d¡Hola!%d sagen. \nUmgangssprachlich wird oft auch nur %d¡Buenas!%d verwendet.

Can't reproduce. it seems like it does actually support linebreaks.
can you share your text? by [edit]ing your post.
maybe there are two \n's. hence, replaceAll would maybe fix it

Von morgens bis mittags begrüßt man sich mit %d¡Buenos  dias!%d \n Danach bis zum Einbruch der Dunkelheit mit %d¡Buenas tardes!%d \nAb dann begrüßt und verabschiedet man sich mit ¡Buenas noches!. \nIn informellen Situationen kann man auch einfach %d¡Hola!%d sagen. \nUmgangssprachlich wird oft auch nur %d¡Buenas!%d verwendet.
This is the text. And this is the actual text that I get when debugging. Seems correct

I had an issue with \n characters not being evaluated when coming from a bad backend. Can you try the following on your Strings: String stringEvaluated(String value) => value.replaceAll('\\n', '\n');
